# How to compare two RegionPlots?

Tags: plotting, regions

I want to compare the regions bounded by the two RegionPlot3D. Following are the two equations of my plots along with their graphical representation:

```
    F1 = RegionPlot3D[ (δ > 
     0 && ((0.8765495860065979` < θ <= 
         0.9252726917778277` && (
          5.5165693397017784`*^7 (-5.112505890383376`*^15 δ + 
             6.9456700794325384`*^16 δ \
θ))/(-6.857951394460775`*^23 - 
           2.052441539265766`*^23 θ + 
           1.3917822876389182`*^24 θ^2) + 
          2.339212652763844`*^-9 Sqrt[-((
            1.` (-1.5438780163828724`*^66 δ^2 - 
               6.271842145024957`*^64 δ^2 θ + 
               4.2067188049000795`*^65 δ^2 \
θ^2))/(-6.857951394460775`*^23 - 
              2.052441539265766`*^23 θ + 
              1.3917822876389182`*^24 θ^2)^2)] < α < -((
          1.1333846813411608`*^16 δ)/(-3.269644300141837`*^15 \
+ 3.269644300141838`*^15 θ))) || (0.9252726917778277` < \
θ < 
         0.9949778354419971` && (
          1.5456509223503857`*^9 (-2.50273625415923`*^14 δ + 
             1.4991308150664`*^14 δ \
θ))/(-1.0243927676182885`*^23 - 
           1.3579091741938968`*^22 θ + 
           1.166687196265354`*^23 θ^2) + 

          1.5767724364264135`*^-7 Sqrt[(
           1.1280800228726955`*^60 δ^2 - 
            7.858877618918956`*^60 δ^2 θ + 
            7.72970364828622`*^60 δ^2 \
θ^2)/(-1.0243927676182885`*^23 - 
             1.3579091741938968`*^22 θ + 
             1.166687196265354`*^23 θ^2)^2] < α < -((
          1.1333846813411608`*^16 δ)/(-3.269644300141837`*^15 \
+ 3.269644300141838`*^15 θ))))), {θ, 0.69, 
   0.9999999999999997`}, {δ, 0, 1}, {α, 1, 100}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Yellow]
```

The plot is given by: 
[image: F1]

For plot2, my input is given by:

```
    F2 = RegionPlot3D[ (δ > 
     0 && ((0.9252726917778277` < θ <= 
         0.9949778354419971` && (
          5.5165693397017784`*^7 (-5.112505890383376`*^15 δ + 
             6.9456700794325384`*^16 δ \
θ))/(-6.857951394460775`*^23 - 
           2.052441539265766`*^23 θ + 
           1.3917822876389182`*^24 θ^2) + 
          2.339212652763844`*^-9 Sqrt[-((
            1.` (-1.5438780163828724`*^66 δ^2 - 
               6.271842145024957`*^64 δ^2 θ + 
               4.2067188049000795`*^65 δ^2 \
θ^2))/(-6.857951394460775`*^23 - 
              2.052441539265766`*^23 θ + 
              1.3917822876389182`*^24 θ^2)^2)] < α < (
          1.5456509223503857`*^9 (-2.50273625415923`*^14 δ + 
             1.4991308150664`*^14 δ \
θ))/(-1.0243927676182885`*^23 - 
           1.3579091741938968`*^22 θ + 
           1.166687196265354`*^23 θ^2) + 
          1.5767724364264135`*^-7 Sqrt[(
           1.1280800228726955`*^60 δ^2 - 
            7.858877618918956`*^60 δ^2 θ + 
            7.72970364828622`*^60 δ^2 \
θ^2)/(-1.0243927676182885`*^23 - 
             1.3579091741938968`*^22 θ + 
             1.166687196265354`*^23 θ^2)^2]) || \
(0.9949778354419971` < θ < 
         0.9999999999999997` && (
          5.5165693397017784`*^7 (-5.112505890383376`*^15 δ + 
             6.9456700794325384`*^16 δ \
θ))/(-6.857951394460775`*^23 - 
           2.052441539265766`*^23 θ + 
           1.3917822876389182`*^24 θ^2) + 
          2.339212652763844`*^-9 Sqrt[-((
            1.` (-1.5438780163828724`*^66 δ^2 - 
               6.271842145024957`*^64 δ^2 θ + 
               4.2067188049000795`*^65 δ^2 \
θ^2))/(-6.857951394460775`*^23 - 
              2.052441539265766`*^23 θ + 
              1.3917822876389182`*^24 θ^2)^2)] < α < -((
          1.1333846813411608`*^16 δ)/(-3.269644300141837`*^15 \
+ 3.269644300141838`*^15 θ))))), {θ, 0.69, 
   0.9999999999999997`}, {δ, 0, 1}, {α, 1, 100}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Yellow]
```

And, this plot is given by:
[image: F2]

Can anyone please help with some command which I can use to find out whether the region bounded by plot 1 is more/less/same as the region bounded by plot 2? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please let me know if you want me to share any other information. I am very sorry, I am a beginner here and also in using Mathematica.

Comment: Can you please format the post for readability? Use code blocks. It should be possible to copy code from your post, and evaluate it. Formatting help is displayed when you click the edit button below your post.

Comment: Ok, I will just try doing that. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have tried to format the post as suggested. Please let me know if it seems better now? Thank you.

Comment: You would get improved plots by including the options `PlotPoints -> 100, 
MaxRecursion -> 5`

Comment: Thank you so much. I will just try doing that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImplicitRegion` to construct computable regions:

```
R1 = ImplicitRegion[(δ > 0 && ...), {{θ, 0.69, 0.9999999999999997`},
                                            {δ, 0, 1}, {α, 1, 100}}];
R2 = ImplicitRegion[...];
```

Then:

```
RegionIntersection[R1, R2]
(* EmptyRegion[3] *)
```

So they seem to not overlap.
You can also see this by comparing their `RegionBounds`:

```
RegionBounds[R1]
RegionBounds[R2]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood these commands. Thanks a lot. Do you also know how to find out the volumes of the regions bounded by the two plots? Basically, the first one represents welfare increase from a change, and the second one represents the welfare decrease from the same change. Therefore, I want to check if the increase in welfare (represented by plot 1) is more than the decrease as shown in Plot 2. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, try `Volume[R1]` or `RegionMeasure[R1]`. It takes much longer for the `R2` though, not sure if it will ever finish.

Comment: Thank you so much, thanks a lot. I shall try using these commands.